# How to Set value of factory from controller?

Tags: angularjs

I created a **factory** below. 
I want to set the value of **page_id field**.
I use two function are **setPageId** and **getPageId** :

```
app.factory('socket', [function ($scope) {
        var onmessageDefer;
        var trustedClose = false;
        debugger;
        var url = 'ws://localhost:8084/javaSocketTest/socket';
        var page_id = '';
        var socket = {
            ws: new WebSocket(url),
            send: function (header, data) {
                var object = {};
                object["type"] = header;
                object["data"] = data;
                if (socket.ws.readyState === 1) {
                    socket.ws.send(object);
                    console.log('send data: ');
                    console.log(object);
                } else {

                }
            },
            setPageId:function(page){
                page_id=page;
                debugger;
            },
            getPageId:function(){
                return page_id;
            }
    };
             return socket;
    }]);
```

And in my Controller, i call function **setPageId** but **page_id** always= ''. 
So How to fix it. what am I wrong ??

```
app.controller('postCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $timeout, $filter, ngTableParams, SweetAlert, PostServices,socket) {

        socket.setPageId('trung');

       });
```

Comment: How are you verifying that the value does not change?

Comment: Also, you cannot inject `$scope` into factories, only controllers and directives

Comment: yes. 
i debugger and print it to console.

Comment: Your `debugger` statement only fires once when the factory is created. That will be **before** anything is able to call `setPageId`

Comment: @Phil  Thanks. 
I will remove it

Comment: oh. 
I call **setPageId** from controller
and call **getPageId** next. 
but nothing changes

I thinks factory maybe load data only once when create

Comment: No, your code should work as you expect. You do appear to have a missing `}` in your factory though. You sure you don't have any other errors in your console?

Comment: Oh. 
missing in this post. 

and No errors in my console.

Comment: Looks fine over here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/CvhqcUeuvWSkY3voFeMH?p=preview

Comment: So sorry. That's my base. 
i put function **setPageId** in a $timeout. 
this is problem, i fix it and it work. 
Thanks bros :) @Phil